# Parsing SD Card in Android

Tags: android, url, xml-parsing

My code stops here on the `sourceURL` declaration and throws an exception:

`java.net.MalformedURLException`: Protocol not found: mnt/sdcard/Android/data...

```
URL sourceUrl = new URL(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Android/data/com.esentral.testdev/"+"temp2.xml");

MyXMLHandler myXMLHandler = new MyXMLHandler();
xr.setContentHandler(myXMLHandler);
xr.parse(new InputSource(sourceUrl.openStream()));
```

Is the case here a mis-conversion of URL-String of some sorts? If so, is there a common workaround? 
I heard SAX is the way to go but it might complicate things further. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Valid URLs start with a protocol.  There's no protocol returned by Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), which returns a file path.  You need to add the file protocol to the beginning of the string.

Comment: Thanks. Good on you.
Will progress from here.

Answer (score 4):

You have to specify protocol like http, ftp, file etc. Here you are accessing it from sdcard so it would be `"file://"` before whole path.

Now modify your code snippet with this,

```
URL sourceUrl = new URL("file://" + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Android/data/com.esentral.testdev/"+"temp2.xml");
MyXMLHandler myXMLHandler = new MyXMLHandler();
xr.setContentHandler(myXMLHandler);
xr.parse(new InputSource(sourceUrl.openStream()));
```